# Using Cognito Hosted UI in Ionic mobile application

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, oauth, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Because of limitations of [Aplify UI Authenticator](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/angular/connected-components/authenticator) and Amplify itself, I'm struggling to get custom scopes (*openid, email, profile*) - in accessToken retrieved after signIn().

Scope is always set to: *aws.cognito.signin.user.admin*.

The question is - how can I implement Hosted UI for OAuth sign-in in Ionic application - which seems to handle different scopes in accessToken?
(target is Android/iOS)

Back in the day I was using in-app-browser, but It's been deprecated and using it can result in ban from app stores.

Or maybe there is a way to use Amplify API flow to get accessToken for custom scopes?

Here are some links already referencing similar problems:
[Not able to get any OAuth or Custom Scopes in Access Token](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/3732#issuecomment-1702116346)
[Custom scopes in access token programmatically](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/issues/684)